# javafx serialize wrapper with color

Tags: javafx, serialization, colors, deserialization, wrapper

EDIT:
I am attempting to serialize a class with these data fields:

```
    private int radius;
    private int strokeWidth;
    private String colorName;
    private CannonBallDrawModeEnum cannonBallDrawModeEnum;
```

There are some methods that convert `colorName` to a `Color`. Right before I serialize I call a method to convert `colorName` back to a `String` to make sure there are no issues. Once I serialize I notice the tag `<color/>` in my text file. When I remove the tag I can deserialize the class with no issue. How do I stop this tag from being serialized?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<serializeWrapper>
    <cannonBallData>
        <cannonBallDrawModeEnum>CIRCLE</cannonBallDrawModeEnum>
        </color>                     //<--------------This line does not belong.
        <colorName>RED</colorName>
        <radius>40</radius>
        <strokeWidth>1</strokeWidth>
    </cannonBallData>
    <pyramidData>
        <height>4</height>
        <name>MyPyramid_1</name>
        <stackingOrder>LeftJustified</stackingOrder>
    </pyramidData>
</serializeWrapper>
```

Comment: Are you using JAXB or are you using Java serialization?

Comment: ```JAXB.marshal``` and ```JAXB.unmarhsal```. The book I'm using does not make that distinction so I am  not sure.

Comment: Can you _create_ and provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Slaw it looks like there was another tag for color added on the serialization, but I am not sure were something like that would have come from.

Comment: Your wrapper class, did the book you're using suggest it or was it your idea? I would expect the former to suggest an adapter since you're using JAXB.

Comment: @Slaw I chose the wrapper since I couldn’t figure out the two class issue. The book only showed one class as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JAXB you should be using an `XmlAdapter` to map the `Color` into, for instance, a `String` and vice versa. Here's an example:

**Main.java:**

```java
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("entity.xml").getAbsoluteFile();
    System.out.println("XML FILE       : " + file);

    Entity entity = new Entity();
    entity.setRadius(24);
    entity.setStrokeWidth(2);
    entity.setColor(Color.RED);

    System.out.println("BEFORE MARSHAL : " + entity);
    JAXB.marshal(entity, file);
    System.out.println("AFTER UNMARSHAL: " + JAXB.unmarshal(file, Entity.class));
  }
}
```

**Entity.java:**

```java
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Entity {

  private Color color;
  private int radius;
  private int strokeWidth;

  @XmlElement
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ColorXmlAdapter.class) // apply adapter
  public Color getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public int getRadius() {
    return radius;
  }

  public void setRadius(int radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public int getStrokeWidth() {
    return strokeWidth;
  }

  public void setStrokeWidth(int strokeWidth) {
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Entity{radius=" + radius + ", strokeWidth=" + strokeWidth + ", color=" + color + "}";
  }
}
```

**ColorXmlAdapter.java:**

```java
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ColorXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Color> {

  @Override
  public Color unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return Color.valueOf(v); // capable of parsing hex color strings
  }

  @Override
  public String marshal(Color v) throws Exception {
    int red = toInt(v.getRed()) << 24;
    int green = toInt(v.getGreen()) << 16;
    int blue = toInt(v.getBlue()) << 8;
    int alpha = toInt(v.getOpacity());

    // Convert to hex color string
    int rgba = red + green + blue + alpha;
    return String.format("#%08X", rgba);
  }

  private static int toInt(double rgbaComponent) {
    return (int) Math.round(255 * rgbaComponent);
  }
}
```

The above will output the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entity>
    <color>#FF0000FF</color>
    <radius>24</radius>
    <strokeWidth>2</strokeWidth>
</entity>
```

Comment: thank you. For reference, do you know why my original example produced the ```</color>``` tag?

Comment: I don't, sorry. I'm not familiar enough with JAXB to deduce what the cause of problematic output might be.